# Remove darkening monitor

Tags: screen, power-management

My monitor goes dark after a while of inactivity.
How do I alter or remove that setting in the Raspberry Pi (debian).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit `/etc/kbd/config`, change `BLANK_TIME` line to

```
BLANK_TIME=0
```

Reboot. You text console is now always on.